# Image slider on Smartface

Tags: javascript, slider, slide, smartface.io, viewpage

I've been trying to code with SmartFace. 
I need to make an image slider. But, I am stuck and don't know where to start.
I want to make something like this :
https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9tIH0hcjKAhWM7hoKHQ4dCIMQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjquery-plugins.net%2Ftag%2Ftouch-enabled-slider&psig=AFQjCNH_vEXXcHB4fajB7f1Pz9x2kmwU7g&ust=1453917230609303

Answer (score 1):

You can make image slider by using scrollview. [This document](http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/scrollview/) help you to create it. Also you can see an image slider example if you download 'Smartface In Action' in App Store.

Here is the sample code:

```
var imageSlider = new SMF.UI.ScrollView({
        top : "10%",
        left : "10%",
        width : "80%",
        height : "60%",
        contentHeight : "200%",
        contentWidth : "100%",
        autoSize : true,
        layoutType : SMF.UI.LayoutType.linear,
        orientation : SMF.UI.Orientation.horizontal,
        enableHorizontalPaging : true,
        enableHorizontalScrolling : true,
        horizontalGap : "0dp",
        verticalGap : "0dp",
    });
Pages.Page1.add(imageSlider);
   function fillScrollView() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var image = new SMF.UI.Image({
                width : "80%",
                height : "30%",
                top : "5%",
                left : "5%",
                image : "myimage.png",
                multipleLine : false
            });
        imageSlider .add(image);
    }
}
fillScrollView();
```